# Consider in COUNT only specific ids

Tags: mysql, sql

I have several shifts which volunteers can choose from a minimum of 6 shifts. I want to know how many volunteers have chosen each of the shifts. Until here it's easy, but it is more tricky if I just want to consider for COUNT only the volunteers who have chosen only 6 shifts.

This is what I am doing, but it's not working at all:

```
SELECT COUNT(volunteer_id), shift_id 
FROM rota
WHERE volunteer_id IN (SELECT volunteer_id FROM rota HAVING 
                       COUNT(volunteer_id) = 6)
GROUP BY shift_id;
```

Edit:

This is an example of the table "rota". In the real life, there are 100 volunteer_id and 15 different shift_id

```
id  volunteer_id   shift_id
1      1               3
2      1               2
3      1               1
4      2               1
5      2               2
6      2               7
7      2               12
8      2               5
9      2               6
10     3               2
11     3               3
n
```

Expected results will be something like this. The column volunteer_id will consider only the volunteers who have selected 6 shifts in the table above:

```
shift_id      COUNT(volunteer_id)
     1                5
     2                32
     3                12
     4                9
     n
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results wold help.

Comment: Help us help you - please share the tables' structure, some sample data and the result you're trying to get for that sample.

Comment: To make it really easy you may consider using `http://sqlfiddle.com/` and showing us a link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the query that will return the `volunteer_id` who have chosen 6 shifts:

```
SELECT volunteer_id FROM rota GROUP BY volunteer_id HAVING COUNT(shift_id) = 6
```

So use it like this:

```
SELECT shift_id, count(distinct volunteer_id) counter FROM rota 
WHERE volunteer_id IN (
  SELECT volunteer_id FROM rota GROUP BY volunteer_id HAVING COUNT(shift_id) = 6
) 
GROUP BY shift_id
```

Comment: Thanks @forpas, but is not exactly that. What I need is `SELECT COUNT(volunteer_id), shift_id FROM rota GROUP BY shift_id` but only including the volunteers who have selected 6 shifts.

Comment: Can you post your expected result for the sample data, or more you posted?

Answer (score 0):

I want to know how many volunteers have chosen each of the shifts

```
SELECT COUNT(volunteer_id) FROM rota GROUP BY shift_id
```

I want to know who are valid volunteers who selected 6 shift

```
SELECT volunteer_id
    FROM (
      SELECT COUNT(shift_id) c FROM rota GROUP BY volunteer_id
    ) as tmp WHERE c=6
```

I want to know how many *valid* volunteers have chosen each of the shifts

```
SELECT COUNT(volunteer_id),shift_id FROM rota
WHERE volunteer_id IN(
    SELECT volunteer_id
    FROM (
      SELECT COUNT(shift_id) c FROM rota GROUP BY volunteer_id
    ) as tmp WHERE c=6

)
GROUP BY shift_id
```